# MongoDB conditional query for array $size

Tags: mongodb-3.0, size

I have a user collection, and each user has different number of id_cards, all id_cards are stored in an array, I can get all users that have 7 id_card by using array $size operator, how do I get the users with say more then 5 id_cards?

Comment: You will have to use aggregation framework.  Refer https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/size/

Comment: Use $gt or $lt based on your requirement

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: can you paste the query you used?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a collection `users` with documents like

```json
{
   _id: "5ffb5796-15d3-4ad4-b40a-6de7a12cb057",
   user_name: "Leeloo Dallas",
   id_cards: [
      {
         card_nr: "G476553G",
         type: "Multipass"
      },
      {
         ...
      }
   ]
}
```

You could then query

```js
db.users.find({"id_cards.4": {$exists: true}})
```

This matches all documents where the `id_cards` array entry with index 4 exists. Index 4 of course being the 5th element. In other words, this returns all users with 5 or more ID cards.